# EF6 generated SQL is not valid SQL server side

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

This one sounds crazy - but fact is following is what I observe:
I have a apsx mvc application connected to a SQL server using EF6.
From time to time I I get exception on the underlaying generated SQL. Like:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'" and "Incorrect syntax near
>   '[Extend1]'

(And variations of this)

In my best opinion that should not happen from a framework like EF.

Luckily I have introduced a SQL interceptor (like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) given me that chance to see the SQL prior to execution.
My first step was to examine the generated SQL - and that looks sane. In an other step I attached a profiler on the SQL server!
And guess what - the SQL that the intercepted logs does not match the SQL recorded in the profiler. (sound fubar, but it is what is observer)
Conclusion is so far: from time to time single characters in the SQL changes (In the observed cases it is commas that becomes formfeed.)

Does anyone on the internet have a clue what could be the background for this?

UPDATE 1: (Requested information)

=== EF Code ===

```
public Customer GetById(string id)
{
    return DbContext.Customers.Include("Address").FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

=== From the Interceptor ===

```
2019-11-06 09:07:14.471 +01:00 [Interceptors.SqlLogInterceptor] [44] [<<username>>] [Debug] SELECT 
     [Limit1].[AddressTypeId] AS [AddressTypeId], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId], 
    [Limit1].[ShowPrebooking] AS [ShowPrebooking], 
    [Limit1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Limit1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
    [Limit1].[Name2] AS [Name2], 
    [Limit1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
    [Limit1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
    [Limit1].[HouseNumber] AS [HouseNumber], 
    [Limit1].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
    [Limit1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Limit1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Limit1].[CountryCode] AS [CountryCode], 
    [Limit1].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
    [Limit1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Limit1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Limit1].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedByUserId] AS [CreatedByUserId], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedDateTime] AS [CreatedDateTime], 
    [Limit1].[UpdatedByUserId] AS [UpdatedByUserId], 
    [Limit1].[UpdatedDateTime] AS [UpdatedDateTime], 
    [Limit1].[DeliveryDescription] AS [DeliveryDescription], 
    [Limit1].[OpeningHoursTo] AS [OpeningHoursTo], 
    [Limit1].[OpeningHoursFrom] AS [OpeningHoursFrom]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId], 
        [Extent1].[ShowPrebooking] AS [ShowPrebooking], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
        [Extent2].[Name2] AS [Name2], 
        [Extent2].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
        [Extent2].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
        [Extent2].[HouseNumber] AS [HouseNumber], 
        [Extent2].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
        [Extent2].[City] AS [City], 
        [Extent2].[State] AS [State], 
        [Extent2].[CountryCode] AS [CountryCode], 
        [Extent2].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
        [Extent2].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent2].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
        [Extent2].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
        [Extent2].[AddressTypeId] AS [AddressTypeId], 
        [Extent2].[CreatedByUserId] AS [CreatedByUserId], 
        [Extent2].[CreatedDateTime] AS [CreatedDateTime], 
        [Extent2].[UpdatedByUserId] AS [UpdatedByUserId], 
        [Extent2].[UpdatedDateTime] AS [UpdatedDateTime], 
        [Extent2].[DeliveryDescription] AS [DeliveryDescription], 
        [Extent2].[OpeningHoursTo] AS [OpeningHoursTo], 
        [Extent2].[OpeningHoursFrom] AS [OpeningHoursFrom]
        FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AddressId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
2019-11-06 09:07:14.471 +01:00 [Yourleman.Ef.Interceptors.SqlLogInterceptor] [44] [<<username>>] [Debug] -- Failed in 1 ms with error: Incorrect syntax near 'Limit1'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

=== Trace from profiler ===

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit1].[AddressTypeId] AS [AddressTypeId], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId], 
    [Limit1].[ShowPrebooking] AS [ShowPrebooking], 
    [Limit1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Limit1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
    [Limit1].[Name2] AS [Name2], 
    [Limit1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
    [Limit1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
    [Limit1].[HouseNumber] AS [HouseNumber], 
    [Limit1].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
    [Limit1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Limit1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Limit1].[CountryCode] AS [CountryCode], 
    [Limit1].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
    [Limit1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Limit1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Limit1].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedByUserId] AS [CreatedByUserId], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedDateTime] AS [CreatedDateTime], 
    [Limit1].[UpdatedByUserId] AS [UpdatedByUserId], 
    [Limit1].[UpdatedDateTime] AS [UpdatedDateTime], 
    [Limit1].[DeliveryDescription] AS [DeliveryDescription], 
    [Limit1].[OpeningHoursTo] AS [OpeningHoursTo] 
    [Limit1].[OpeningHoursFrom] AS [OpeningHoursFrom]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId], 
        [Extent1].[ShowPrebooking] AS [ShowPrebooking], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
        [Extent2].[Name2] AS [Name2], 
        [Extent2].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
        [Extent2].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
        [Extent2].[HouseNumber] AS [HouseNumber], 
        [Extent2].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
        [Extent2].[City] AS [City], 
        [Extent2].[State] AS [State], 
        [Extent2].[CountryCode] AS [CountryCode], 
        [Extent2].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
        [Extent2].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent2].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
        [Extent2].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
        [Extent2].[AddressTypeId] AS [AddressTypeId], 
        [Extent2].[CreatedByUserId] AS [CreatedByUserId], 
        [Extent2].[CreatedDateTime] AS [CreatedDateTime], 
        [Extent2].[UpdatedByUserId] AS [UpdatedByUserId], 
        [Extent2].[UpdatedDateTime] AS [UpdatedDateTime], 
        [Extent2].[DeliveryDescription] AS [DeliveryDescription], 
        [Extent2].[OpeningHoursTo] AS [OpeningHoursTo], 
        [Extent2].[OpeningHoursFrom] AS [OpeningHoursFrom]
        FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AddressId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'2341234'
```

Examine the bytes showed that after the  [OpeningHoursTo] there is a Form Feed character (\u000C)

Comment: Is this a random bug, or does it repeat only for specific queries? Personally, I don't work with EF, so I probably wont be able to provide an answer, however, if you could post one of the generated SQL Statements that's causing these errors someone might be able to see something you've missed.

Comment: Would you be able to post an example EF query you have and the SQL that is generated? Can you also check what the SQL Profiler provide when the code you have is executed?

Comment: Note that SQL Profiler does not, in actuality, record statements exactly as they are passed in either -- specifically, for RPC calls (i.e. statements with parameters, which is most of what EF will generate) the actual parameter values are formatted as T-SQL literals, even though they're really passed as binary values in the underlying TDS stream. All this is a long-winded way of saying that Profiler doesn't always show the literal truth either. An accurate comparison would need the actual statements you see, regardless.

Comment: Building on what @JeroenMostert said, can you run a trace on the server itself and capture the actual statement(s) that are being executed?

Comment: @zohar it is random - cannot find a pattern on it.

Comment: @Angelo I could but the only difference in the queries is the single flipped char. It was the comparison you request that revealed the difference.

Comment: Maybe I lost the train. I used the profiler to generate the trace - could you elaborate what you are asking from me?

Comment: Post the EF codes you have, and then the trace generated by the profiler here. Can you also confirm that you are not making any modification to your queries prior to running it (i.e. concatenating variables, parameters, etc.).

Comment: Added the requested information. (Fun fact, today the issue seams to be gone - however still would like to understand what caused this)

Comment: When we convert line 25 ([Limit1].[OpeningHoursTo] AS [OpeningHoursTo]) to binary format, it looks like a bit has been flipped somewhere after the query was generated and logged by EF6 in the application. We are just really puzzled as to where this could happen.

Comment: Problem reoccurred after the weekend.

Comment: After some digging today, I discovered that we also experience the issue when calling a web service where the argument is serialized to XML. The XSD validation in the web service has failed a few times, one of the times because <Address1> was changed to <ADdress1>, which again is a filpped bit. The XML logged on the application server before sending it is correct.

Comment: "a randomly flipped bit" points to a faulty hardware...

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov Yes this is our best guess at the moment. Scary part is that we haven't seen the error since November 13th and no one has a clue about why or what changed.

Answer (score 1):

Lo and behold, on the 3rd of February, the error returned out of nowhere. All traffic out of our production server seemed to be affected and our customers would experience random errors.

Using log files and Wireshark on the server hosting the website we could rule out that particular server, since the data in the TCP packages was correct. We could also rule out the database server and another application server, since requests to both servers would fail in the same way.

In the end, Infrastructure was able to isolate the issue to a defective port on a switch in the network. After disabling this port, the issues was resolved instantly.